# ResourceDictionary Merge behaviour

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls, resourcedictionary

In my project I am trying to embed source code from Avalon Wizard but there is something strange happening and I am not able to successful  integrate it.

I have the following structure in my Custom control library

- Wizard

  - Themes

    - Aero.NormalColor.xaml
    - Aero2.NormalColor.xaml
    - AeroWizardHeader.xaml
    - Generic.xaml
    - Wizard97.xaml
    - WizardAero.xaml
    - Generic.xaml
- Themes

  - Generic.xaml

Inside my Generic.xaml I have the following delcaration

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="CuratioCMS.Client.UI;Component/Wizard/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

and inside Wizard/Themes/Generic.xaml here is how I have my MergedDictionaries defined

```
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="CuratioCMS.Client.UI;Component/Wizard/Themes/Wizard97.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="CuratioCMS.Client.UI;Component/Wizard/Themes/WizardAero.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="CuratioCMS.Client.UI;Component/Wizard/Themes/AeroWizardHeader.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

According to Avalon implementation there is one more MergedDictionary provided inside Aero.NormalColor.xaml which looks like this

```
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="CuratioCMS.Client.UI;Component/Wizard/Themes/AeroWizardHeader.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

My problem is that I am not able to use my own class library in my project as designer throws exception which is: **Cannot locate resource 'wizard/themes/curatiocms.client.ui;component/wizard/themes/wizard97.xaml'.**

If I change Path inside Wizard/Theme/Generic.xaml then error goes away but Wizard is not able to provide Aero functionality and even designer does not work ex expected.

Let me also say, that I decided to have this kind of architecture because according to extended WPF toolkit this is very clean way .

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: ok I changed CuratioCMS.Client.UI;Component/Wizard/ with /CuratioCMS.Client.UI;Component/Wizard/ so I added / symbol at the beginning everywhere but still can not get Aero effect I am sure there is something wrong with dictionaries because If I move everything up out of Wizard folder it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the full [pack URI syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28VS.85%29.aspx)?

Have you tried changing 'Component' to 'component'? Also make sure the dictionary has it's build action set to Resource and you are correctly referencing your CuratioCMS.Client.UI assembly.

Comment: I tried using Pack URI no result Changing uppercase C to c did not give any result as well what do u mean by referencing  correctly? and which resource dictionary to set as resource not page? if I edit all dictionaries build action to resource then I have an exception with BooleanToVisibilityConverter'.'

Comment: With regards to the referencing the reason we use this 'CuratioCMS.Client.UI;component' is to direct the current assembly to point to the referenced assembly. In your project that contains Generic.xaml make sure that CuratioCMS.Client.UI is listed under References in Solution Explorer. If all of the dictionaries are in the same assembly then you should not be using 'CuratioCMS.Client.UI;component'

Comment: I do not get your point if u ever looked ad Extended WPF toolkit this is the way they use dictionaries. and this also makes sure not conflict with other assemblies and yes generic.xaml is inside custom user control library and it will wrap up other controls as well

Comment: With regards to the build action please see msdn. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx

Comment: The reason this is done with Extended WPF toolkit is because it is added as a referenced assembly. If you look under references WPFToolkit will be displayed. If you are trying to access resource dictionaries in the current assembly you should not be using the 'CuratioCMS.Client.UI;component'. It should simply be Source="../Wizard/Themes/AeroWizardHeader.xaml"

Comment: Let me explain e little bit. CuratioCMS.Client.UI is a separate assembly which holds (will hold all custom controls) I have another executable ProgramA.exe and inside progtamA project I have CuratioCMS.Client.UI added as a reference, so I think in this situation leaving CuratioCMS.Client.UI;component is mandatory right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17677/discussion-between-rati-ge-and-alexw)